# Ionic 2 ion-navbar Back with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a page with an ion-navbar, when I navigate to the next page I use the following:

```
this.nav.push(SubCategoryPage, {
employeeModel: this.employeeModel
});
```

It passes the param parameter successfully to the next page.

When I am in the next page (`SubCategoryPage`), I update the parameter object (`employeeModel`). My question is, when I click the **back** arrow to return to the previous page, how do I pass the modified parameter object (`employeeModel`) back?

When **back** is clicked, the `ngOnDestroy` is called, do I use this, but then how do I pass the parameter object?

OR, is there some other scope I should put the object in? (How do you pass objects from one page to another, including back?) What's best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommending caching the object in a provider. That way, its properties will remain the same when navigating between your components. By caching, all I mean its a simple get and setter.

Comment: tothefux, I do create my object as a provider, but it looses the properties I set on it. I have a Master/Detail set up, when I go to the Detail, I set properties on the object, but when I return to the Master via the back button, the object does not have the properties. I go back to the Detail, and the properties are also absent.

Comment: You can use a shared service to store the `employeeModel` just like you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ionic2/4407/using-services-in-ionic2#t=201608042004344717971).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

in app.ts I need to set the object, then it is shared between pages

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [EmployeeModel]);
```

ref: https://www.joshmorony.com/an-in-depth-explanation-of-providers-in-ionic-2/